# How do I see all the regular code updates made in my Git repo in azure devops?

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, repo

I have imported my github repo in one of the project in my Azure devops. But when I push latest code to my github repo it doesn't reflect in Azure.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you've done the import, in general you can look at the commits from the **`Repos -> Commits`** Menu

[image]

Comment: I imported the github repo in azure from Repo>File in the menu

Comment: then you should see them

Comment: I see the project in my azure repo, the problem is when I make a code push to my github repo it doesn't reflect in azure

Comment: check if you have set the remote url correctly, otherwise clone the repo from azure devops and make changes and see

Comment: I'm new here, my agenda is to "See all latest code updates(push/commits) made in my github repo in the Azure devops" , so that it would be helpful to set the pipeline in azure. Can you please guide on it other than setting the pipeline

Comment: After you import the code to github, use the azure devops repo url and clone it on your local machine. Whatever changes you push it will be reflected there. On the pipelines there are enough resources available

Comment: I'm still trying to do that. My agenda is when I push my latest code to my git repo that should automatically reflect in the azure devops repo. Apologies its little confused since i'm new to this

Comment: Thats not possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237691/discussion-between-bharath-kashyap-and-sajeetharan).